# Сode Review удаленного репозитория

Tags: git, ssh, поиск-программ

Есть личный удаленный репозиторий (git) с доступом по ssh (ключик).
Необходимо делать Сode Review этого репозитория.
Какие есть бесплатные альтернативы (Crucible не подходит)?

Comment: «Личный» — это значит private access? А кто делает вычитку, сам?

Comment: Доступ к репозиторию имеют парочку разрабтчиков. Ревью делает один из них.

Comment: А почему Crucible не подходит?

Comment: @Qwertiy сам не тестировал, но тот для кого настраивал эту штуку сказал что есть какое то неудобство с комментированием кода.

Comment: Из того, чем пользовался, мне crusible больше всего нравился.

Answer (score 3):

Нашел отличную альтернативу (относительно бесплатную). JetBrains Upsource. Запустил Docker контейнером и подключил к нему свой репозиторий. С поставленой задачей справляется. Почему относительно бесплатный - насколько я понял до 10 человек лицензию покупать не надо.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать [ReviewBoard](https://pypi.org/project/ReviewBoard/) на локальном или удаленном хосте. Демо [вот тут](https://demo.reviewboard.org/r/).